# Why qt webkit can't load local image?

Tags: qt, webkit

I am loading an html file into QWebView:

```
<img src="/home/xxx/.config/xxx/chat_img/test.png" />
<img src="test.png" />
<img src="file://test.png" />
```

But nothing gets displayed. If I replace the image src with an online image (external source), such as  http://domain.com/file.png Then it is displayed. So what I want to know is why QWebView isn't loading my local files? 
Thanks.

Comment: `qDebug() << QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path/test.png");` and paste it into the <img />

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I tried to create a QWebView this way:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QWebFrame>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView view;
    view.page()->mainFrame()->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(html_file));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

and both an absolute path or an uri (you were missing a slash) are working:

```
<img src="/abs/path/to/image.jpg" />
<img src="file:///abs/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: It's very strange. On my computer, it only can work if I use `<img src="file:/path/imgage" />. And I'm sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: According to this, those should work: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp.